# Prove that $\ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \ \binom{2n}{n-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{n-1-i}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

> Prove that: $$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \ \binom{2n}{n-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{n-1-i}$$

I've no idea how to approach this.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Comment: You could try generating series, or proving a recurrence, or induction, perhaps?

Comment: Hint: Vandermonde convolution.

Comment: @SeanRoberson best hint...it's direct with Vandermonde identity +1

Comment: @SeanRoberson The combinatorial proof for Vandermonde's identity was most understandable for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \ \binom{2n}{n-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{n-1-i}$

posing $n=m$ and $r=n-1$

$\binom{n+m}{r}=\sum_{i=0}^{r}\binom{n}{i}\binom{m}{r-i}$

Vandermonde 's Identity

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity